# What is runtime error in this program of FizzBuzz?

Tags: java

It run fine in my pc IDE but when I submit this program to online IDE like ideone.com it gives run time error. I need to submit this program to codeeval.com to complete my challange but again there is error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 1, userinput;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Number till you want to get your Fizz & Buzz series");
        userinput = scan.nextInt();
        while (n != userinput) {
            if ((n % 3 == 0) && (n % 5 == 0)) {
                System.out.println(" FizzBuzz ");
            } else if (n % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(" Fizz ");
            } else if (n % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println(" Buzz ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(" " + n + " ");
            }

            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the `public` keyword in front of `class FizzBuzz {`.

Comment: I think your "Enter" key has a problem

Comment: Does it work when you run it on your machine?

Comment: I just tried it on ideone and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

"Error: Could not find or load main class Main" hints at the issue.

If you go to ideone.com the default code is this:

```
/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
```

So the class needs to be `class Ideone` or `public class Main` to compile there.

Comment: not correct. The class can be renamed with it still working. In fact, the example posted [does work in ideone](http://ideone.com/sozPcW)